# Qt Creator "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt-creator, libraries

Let me start off by saying I'm fairly new to Qt. That being said, I'm having dependency issues.

I am trying to use mclmcrrt.h in the Matlab directory. From my *.pro file I right click->add library->external library->browse, etc. and I get the following:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime/v714/extern/lib/win32/microsoft/ -lmclmcrrt
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime/v714/extern/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime/v714/extern/include
```

This looks similar to what I've seen in other places using the INCLUDEPATH, etc. Also, in my included header file that's calling mclmcrrt.h I have:

```
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
```

No matter what, I can't get rid of the error: "mclmcrrt.h: No such file or directory"

I looked around and tried a lot of things.  I got this working in Visual Studio, but can't seem to get it here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces in paths break the parser, try this:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../"Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime"/v714/extern/lib/win32/microsoft/ -lmclmcrrt
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../"Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime"/v714/extern/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../"Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime"/v714/extern/include
```

Comment: I guess that's the definition of a rookie mistake. Now I just have to work out the 72 errors I have now that it compiles >.< Thank you!